# How to remove bounding box extents based on reflectance values of the image of Landsat8 by using R programming

Tags: r, remote-sensing, extents, landsat

I have taken the reflectance image from Landsat8 bands.

Now the extents of bounding box showing negative values , to proceed to my next level of the process i need to remove this negative values and make them as NULL.

Can you suggest the procedure to do that using R code?

Comment: Can you describe the problem that you are facing with more detail? I have a hard time figuring out exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly: You want to reclassify any values below zero to NA? If yes, see http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/reclassify

Answer (score 1):

I assume you imported the data using the raster package. If not you should have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html)

If you haven't imported the landsat data as a stack. you could do the following.

```
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)

s <- stack('path_to_your_file')
s[s==value] <- NA
writeRaster(s, filename, format, ...)
```

Where "value" is your negative value around the scene. In my example it is replaced by NA. You could also use another value like 0.

If you want to do the same for the single bands (assuming they use 0 for the background) before calculation. You can do the following:

```
r <- raster('path_to_band_x_file')
r[r==0] <- NA
writeRaster(r, filename, format, ...)
```

You can use the "dir" function and a for loop to loop through the single bands.

Comment: can I specify the negative value directly or will it changes for image to image

Comment: I can't answer that precisely, as it is depending on what you did with the image and how the original input looks like. It might be that the original input bands in DN have 0 (zero) values in the background. If this is the case you could use the same procedure to set all background values of the single bands to NA before doing your calculations for reflectance.

Comment: yes original Lansat Band5 image having 0 's in the background

Comment: Is it better to perform background values to NA before reflectance or else after

Comment: I've added a few lines to my answer. I am not sure about Landsat8 but calculation of reflectance for Landsat7 has different corrction factors for each band. Thus the background value would change for each scene and each band. By setting the background to NA before calculation you don't have to find the exact background value after calculation. But be careful, to set the values to NA you have to switch from integer to float, else it won't work I guess.

Comment: after the changing of the values to NA also its showing  the the same value

Comment: @user28536, did you check if there are pixels in your image that are precisly zero? If you want to set all pixels to NA that are smaller or equal to zero, then you have to use: `r[r<=0] <- NA`

Comment: How about for negative values like -0.104379

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `reclassify` from the `raster package`:

```
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)

s <- stack('path_to_your_file')

#check if s is an Raster*object
str(s) #Is Formal class 'RasterLayer'?
#If not: 
raster(s)

s_reclass <- reclassify(s , rcl=cbind(-Inf,0, NA)) #works only for Raster*object
#rcl is a matrix with 3 values (see ?reclassify)! Here it means: reclassify in all bands all values between minus Infinite and 0 to NA
```

(in my test `reclassify` is faster than `s[s<0]<- NA`)

Comment: Important: `rcl ` needs always a matrix with 3 values:  The first two columns are "from" "to" of the input values, and the third column "becomes" has the new value for that range (see `?reclassify`). So `rcl=cbind(-0.240596,0,NA)` would be valid and  `rcl=cbind(-0.240596,NA)` is not valid!

Comment: when i tried reclassify on the band its changing 0 to NA

Comment: when i try that (reclassify) on the reflconS() function output (written in writeGDAL) its not working why?

Comment: Can u suggest which of the following is correct reclassify before reflectance or after?

Comment: its not happen sir tell me the alternative

Comment: is there any way to specify the <0 condition(logical) in cbind()

Comment: Are you sure, that you are using `reflconS()` correctly? Did you try to plot the result image `plot(resultimage)`. what is the range of plottet values? Are your boundaries of `rcl` within the range of your image? I even run my code with `reflconS(s, 1,1,50)` and reclassify is working perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29704/discussion-between-iris-and-user28536).